# Eigenvalues of a quasi-circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

The following matrix cropped up in a model I am building of a dynamical system:

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 - \alpha & \alpha/2 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & \alpha/2\\
\alpha/2 & 1-\alpha & \alpha/2 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \alpha/2 & 1-\alpha & \alpha/2 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & \alpha/2 & 1-\alpha & \alpha/2\\
\alpha/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \alpha/2 & 1-\alpha\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

It is a [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) and a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), and has equal values in the diagonal.

I am interested in the eigenvalues of this matrix, and it was easy to derive them from the properties listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). It turns out that for size $n$,

$$
\lambda_k = 1 - \alpha \left(1 - \cos\frac{\pi k (n-2)}{n}\right), \qquad k\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\},
$$

and in the limiting case,

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lambda_k = 1 - \alpha(1 + (-1)^k) = \begin{cases}1-2\alpha & k \textrm{ even}\\ 1 & k \textrm{ odd}\end{cases}
$$

This is interesting for my study, because an eigenvalue of $1$ that is independent of $\alpha$ implies a marginally stable system that cannot be fully stabilized.

Now, I am interested in a slightly modified system, represented by the matrix below. This matrix is exactly like the one above save for the first and last rows, and is still a stochastic matrix with equal values in the diagonal.

I am wondering whether it is possible to derive the eigenvalues of this matrix, even if only for the limiting case.

---

$$A^\prime=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 - \alpha & \color{red} \alpha & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & \color{red} 0\\
\alpha/2 & 1-\alpha & \alpha/2 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \alpha/2 & 1-\alpha & \alpha/2 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & \alpha/2 & 1-\alpha & \alpha/2\\
\color{red} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \color{red} \alpha & 1-\alpha\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That matrix is also tri-diagonal. It's not too difficult to write a recurrence relation for its characteristic determinant, solve it, set the result to zero, and solve for the eigenvalues. Look for proofs of the eigenvalues of tri-diagnoal Toeplitz matrices, which look similar, to see how it's done.

Comment: I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues), as well, which may be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Still eigenvalue $1$ makes it marginally stable.

Comment: Expanding the determinant of $\lambda I-A$ along the first and then the last rows it is easy to express the characteristic polynomial of the matrix in terms of the central minors of size $n-2$ and $n-4$ that have no irregularity, i.e. the standard circulant matrices with known characteristic polynomials. I have no time now, but I believe you can fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this matrix:
$$M:=\left[\begin{array}{r} 2&-2\\ -1&2&-1\\ &-1&2&-1\\ &&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&-1&2&-1\\ &&&&-1&2&-1\\ &&&&&-2&2 \end{array}\right].$$
Then your matrix $A'$ is given by $$A' = I -\frac{\alpha}{2} M.$$
Let $D:=\text{diag}(1/\sqrt{2}, 1, 1, \ldots, 1, 1, 1/\sqrt{2})$.
Upon reading *Discrete Cosine and Sine Transforms: General Properties, Fast Algorithms and Integer Approximations* (Britanak, Yip and Rao; $2006$), I found out (by trial and error, mostly) that the columns of this asymmetric matrix:
$$P:=\left[\cos\left(\frac{jk\pi}{n-1}\right)\right]^{n-1}_{j,k=0} \cdot D$$
are eigenvectors of $M$, corresponding to (increasing) eigenvalues $$\left[4\sin^2\left(\frac{k}{n-0.5}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]^{n-1}_{j=0}.$$
Let $\Lambda$ be the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $M$. Then since $A'$ is so nicely defined, $$A'=I-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}M=PP^{-1}-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}P\Lambda P^{-1}=P(I-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\Lambda)P^{-1},$$
so $A'$ has eigenvalues
$$\left[1-2\alpha\sin^2\left(\frac{k}{n-0.5}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]^{n-1}_{j=0}$$
(albeit decreasingly ordered, assuming $\alpha>0$; you may want to flip the $\cos(\ldots)$ columns left-to-right inside of $P$.)

Also, note that $D^2 M = L_{\text{path}}$, the Laplacian matrix of an undirected path graph with $n$ vertices, but you cannot use the eigendecomposition of $L_{\text{path}}(=Q_{\text{path}} \Lambda_{\text{path}} Q {}^{\text{T}}_{\text{path}}$ since $M \mapsto D^2 M$ is not a similarity transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, spectral graph theory has the analytic solution for this problem.

Let $L$ be the graph Laplacian for the path graph. Then $L$ is tri-diagonal with $[1,2,2,...,2,1]$ on the diagonal and $-1$'s on the super and sub diagonals. Then the matrix $A'$ is given by $$A'=I-\frac{\alpha}2 L.$$ Now since every vector in $\mathbb{C}^N$ is an eigenfunction of $I$, every eigenfunction $\chi_j$ of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ will be an eigenfunction of $A'$ with eigenvalue $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\lambda_j$. Thus, to solve the problem stated hereinbefore, one needs only to solve eigenvalue problem of the path graph. The derivation of which can be found [here](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/2009/lect02-09.pdf).

To summarize the results, the eigenvalues of $L$ are $\lambda_j = 2-2\cos(\frac{\pi j}{N})$ and may be obtained by mapping the cycle graph with $2N$ vertices to the path graph with $N$ vertices.

Interestingly, the cycle graph with $N$ vertices also yields a method for finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ as $$A=I-\frac{\alpha}2 L_c,$$ where $L_c$ is the graph Laplacian for the cycle graph with $N$ vertices. If you let $v_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}[\omega^{0j}, \omega^{1j}, ..., \omega^{(N-1)j}]^T$ for $\omega=e^{2\pi i/N}$ (i.e. $v_j$ is a column of the DFT matrix) then $$L_cv_j = (2\omega^{0}-\omega^{j}-\omega^{-j})v_j = (2-2\cos(2\pi j/N))v_j.$$
Hence, $Av_j = (1-\alpha(1-\cos(2\pi j/N)))v_j$ (so I think the indexing in the question might be a bit off) and the DFT matrix forms an orthonormal eigenbasis that diagonalizes $A$. To get a real orthonormal eigenbasis for $A$ (which is guaranteed to exist because $A$ is real and symmetric), taking combinations $w_j=1/2(v_j+v_{N-j})$ and $w_{N-j} = i/2 (v_j-v_{N-j})$ will do the trick.

Comment: The matrix $L$ for which $A'=I-\frac{\alpha}{2}L$ is not the Laplacian for a graph path; look at the first and last rows of $A'$.

Comment: On a side note, I prefer the change of basis matrix for real circulant symmetric matrices to be of cosines and sines rather than the DFT.

Comment: Yeah, apparently I misread the original matrix. Oh well, it's just a bit of me rambling about the cycle graph Laplacian. I always like the DFT version as I'm an harmonic analyst at heart, but I'm not a fanatic about it.